# I have two graphic cards, how do I know which graphic card is using which port(HDMI, thunderbolt, usb) with windows 10?

Tags: usb, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Is there a way to inspect these information with cmd or powershell commands?
I did some experiments, it seems HDMI is always possessed by the Nvidia card.

Furthermore, if I use a hdmi-usb converter, then the video signal comes in via the normal USB port. Which card will it use?

Comment: Do you have the Nvidia Control Panel app installed?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes I have it. These information is visible there?

Comment: Read about [Nvidia Optimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus).

Comment: @J.R. yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`) and switch it to *View→Devices by connection* mode.

Expand the tree (starting with "ACPI-compliant PC") until you find your graphics cards, and although it doesn't show *ports*, the actually connected *displays* should show up under the cards.

(In laptops, however, I think HDMI is *usually* wired to the internal GPU, as this allows the discrete GPU to be completely powered off when not needed. When the dGPU is used by a game, it only renders graphics but then transfers them to the iGPU to be displayed.)

> Furthermore, if I use a hdmi-usb converter, then the video signal comes in via the normal USB port. Which card will it use?

Neither. If it's an active HDMI-USB converter, then it's a completely separate device from any of your GPUs.

(Also, if it were an HDMI *output* it'd show up as a third "video card"; but if it's an input, I think it actually counts as a capture device instead.)

On the other hand, if it's a passive USB Type C adapter for HDMI, then the process for determining the GPU is the same as for "real" HDMI ports.